# Find a Conditional Distribution of $X$ given $Y$ with a Constant CDF

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, density-function

I have a challenge with an assignment.

"The random variables $X$ and $Y$ has the following joint probability density function $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
2  & 0<x<y<1 \\
0 & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$
Find the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$ and use it to calculate $P(X>5 \ | \ Y=0.7)$"

I was taught that $0<x<y<1$ is also equivalent to $0<x<1, x<y<1$

I have calculated the marginal density for $f_Y(y)$ as $2$
$$f_Y(y) = \int_0^1 f(x,y)\operatorname dx \\ = \int_0^1 2 \operatorname dx \\ = 2
$$

And then the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$ as $1$
$$f(x\mid y) = \frac{f(x,y)}{f_Y(y)} \\ = \frac{2}{2} \\ = 1
$$

And herein I'm stuck. How do I yet find $P(X>5 \ | \ Y=0.7)$ or is my approach wrong?

Comment: You must mention the support of the marginal/conditional density as you have stated for the joint density. As you do not consider the support, your answers do not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing has to do with the support of your random variable. Perhaps you will notice that you integrate over the condition $0<x<1$, but that leaves the other condition $x<y<1$ as the support for your marginal density for $Y$. This cannot be right, because there should be no $x$ left in sight.

The support of $f(x,y)$ in the following graph is the intersection of the green and blue regions:

[image]

To get the marginal density for $Y$, we want to integrate along $\operatorname dx$, so horizontally through the intersected region. This tells me the integral should be as follows:

$f_Y(y) = \int_0^y 2 \operatorname dx = \begin{cases} 2y: & 0<y<1 \\ 0: & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

Note that you can see this analytically (i.e. not by graphing it) simply by your condition $0<x<y<1$ restricts $x<y$, which means this should be your upper bound when integrating.

As you know, $f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \cfrac{f(x,y)}{f_Y(y)} = \begin{cases}\cfrac 1y: & 0<x<y<1 \\ 0: & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

$$\therefore f_{X|Y=.7}(x|.7)  = \begin{cases}\cfrac 1{.7}: & 0<x<.7 \\ 0: & \text{otherwise}\end{cases} \quad \therefore \ P(X>5 \mid Y=0.7) = \int_5^\infty 0 \operatorname dx = 0$$

It's a little odd that this is the answer - maybe you mistyped and meant $P(X>.5 \mid Y=.7)?$ Either way, this is the process to do it.

Comment: with $f_Y(y) = 2y$ I am getting conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$ as $$f(x\mid y) = \frac{f(x,y)}{f_Y(y)} \\ = \frac{2}{2y} \\ = \frac{1}{y}$$ but this doesn't help me (I still do not know how to) calculate $P(X>5 | Y=0.7)$.

Comment: @ArthurEzenwanne Completed the problem in an edit

Comment: My bad, it is $X>0.5$. My assignment options is either {1, 2/3, 0, 2/7}. Using $$\int_.5^\infty \cfrac 1{.7} \operatorname dx \\ = \infty$$ which is not in my assignment options. Well, I will select $1$ as my option answer. Thanks @jeremy909!

Comment: @ArthurEzenwanne Hang on arthur! $P(X>.5 \mid Y = 0.7) = \int_{.5}^{.7}\cfrac{1}{.7}\operatorname dx + \int_{.7}^\infty 0 \operatorname dx$. Check the support of the conditional pdf!